# How do I make a checkbox_tag sticky in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.x/ ruby 2.x

I am using a checkbox to select records for additional processing. I want to make the checkboxes sticky when using a sort or paginate.

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%= check_box_tag "document_ids[]", document.id %></td>
    <td><%= document.id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to document.document_title, document %></td>
     <removed irrelevent code>
<% end %>
<%= paginate @documents %>

  Send Checked Documents as an attachment :  <%= submit_tag "Next" %>
```

The following are the two defs from my controller. If the user simply checked boxes, did not sort or paginate(kaminari), and clicked the next button, the index.multiple def/view would show the documents that were checked.

However, if I check a box and then try to sort or go to the next page, I lose the boxes that were checked, they become unchecked.

```
def index
    #----------------------------------------------------------------
    # index is the method for the main documents listing. We need to pass parameters for sorting (sortable in application_helper) and
    # kaminari's paginate
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------
    @documents = Document.all
    if params[:direction] && params[:sort] then    # missing sort and direction params cause error. This filters for missing and provide a default view
      @documents = Document.order(params[:sort] + ' ' + params[:direction]).page params[:page]
    else
      @documents = Document.order(:id).page params[:page]
    end
  end

  # ------------------------------------------------- index multiple ------------------------------------

  def index_multiple
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # index multiple is for the page after the index. The user has checked checkboxes and those
    # items will be displayed.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $doc_ids = params[:document_ids]     # get the parameters from the checkboxes. send_message converted the params to integers


   if params[:document_ids] then

        @documents = Document.find(params[:document_ids])
     else
       redirect_to  documents_path, :notice => "****************  You must select at least one item **************"
   end

  end
```

What is the best way to make the checkboxes sticky?

Answer (score 0):

According to rails docs, you can set the checkbox as checked/unchecked using the third parameter: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

Modify your code to the following and see if it works:

```
<%= check_box_tag "document_ids[]", document.id, params[:document_ids].include?(document.id) %>
```